# Using multiple features with DataTables.js

Tags: javascript, drupal-6, datatables

I'm having some trouble running multiple features (or "Extras") with my [DataTables.js](http://datatables.net/) plug-in that's in a Drupal 6 module.  When initializing my datatable with each feature independently, everything works as expected. However, when I try to initialize the features together, only the last initialized feature is enabled. In the code below, I am trying to initialize both [ColReorder](http://datatables.net/extras/colreorder/) and [ColVis](http://datatables.net/extras/colvis/). As executed, only ColVis is enabled when I run my program.

Thanks!

*script.js*

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("tableID").dataTable( {
            "sDom": 'Rlfrtip',
            "sDom": 'C<"clear">lfrtip'
        } );
    });
})(jQuery);
```

*drupal.module*

```
drupal_add_css("path/demo_page.css");
drupal_add_css("path/demo_table.css");
drupal_add_js("path/jquery.js");
drupal_add_js("path/jquery.dataTables.js");

drupal_add_css("path/ColReorder.css");
drupal_add_js("path/ColReorder.js");

drupal_add_css("path/ColVis.css");
drupal_add_js("path/ColVis.js");

drupal_add_js("path/script.js");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have multiple `sDom` definitions in the initialization routine.
Try

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("tableID").dataTable( {
            "sDom": 'C<"clear">Rlfrtip'
        } );
    });
})(jQuery);
```

instead.